# Unable to upload file on box.com in readable form

Tags: integration

Hello everyone,
                            I am doing integration salesforce with box.com when i uplod file that time first i convert blob into base 64 encoded string then send file using rest api after uploading  file my file in  not readable form it meanse file is encoded. And i am sending file in body as a blob and also try in body but i can't sucess. so give me some idea that how i can solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploading data into box.com uses content type as multipart/form-data.Posting multipart form data through apex HTTP has been challenging and there is some amount of work done in below blog

http://enreeco.blogspot.it/2013/01/salesforce-apex-post-mutipartform-data.html

All thanks to that blog and I was able to upload files to box .Below is code snippet that may hep you

```
 private void uploadFile(String folderId,Attachment file,String token){
  String boundary = '----------------------------741e90d31eff';
  String header = '--'+boundary+'\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="'+file.name+'";\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream';
  // GW: Do not prepend footer with \r\n, you'll see why in a moment
  // String footer = '\r\n--'+boundary+'--'; 
  String footer = '--'+boundary+'--';             
  String headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
  while(headerEncoded.endsWith('=')){
   header+=' ';
   headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
  }
  String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file.body);
  // GW: Do not encode footer yet
  // String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));

  Blob bodyBlob = null;
  String last4Bytes = bodyEncoded.substring(bodyEncoded.length()-4,bodyEncoded.length());
 // GW: replacement section to get rid of padding without corrupting data
 if(last4Bytes.endsWith('==')) {
    // The '==' sequence indicates that the last group contained only one 8 bit byte
    // 8 digit binary representation of CR is 00001101
    // 8 digit binary representation of LF is 00001010
    // Stitch them together and then from the right split them into 6 bit chunks
    // 0000110100001010 becomes 0000 110100 001010
    // Note the first 4 bits 0000 are identical to the padding used to encode the
    // second original 6 bit chunk, this is handy it means we can hard code the response in
    // The decimal values of 110100 001010 are 52 10
    // The base64 mapping values of 52 10 are 0 K
    // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 for base64 mapping table
    // Therefore, we replace == with 0K
    // Note: if using \n\n instead of \r\n replace == with 'oK'
    last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,2) + '0K';
    bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
    // We have appended the \r\n to the Blob, so leave footer as it is.
    String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
    bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);
  } else if(last4Bytes.endsWith('=')) {
    // '=' indicates that encoded data already contained two out of 3x 8 bit bytes
    // We replace final 8 bit byte with a CR e.g. \r
    // 8 digit binary representation of CR is 00001101
    // Ignore the first 2 bits of 00 001101 they have already been used up as padding
    // for the existing data.
    // The Decimal value of 001101 is 13
    // The base64 value of 13 is N
    // Therefore, we replace = with N
    // Note: if using \n instead of \r replace = with 'K'
    last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,3) + 'N';
    bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
    // We have appended the CR e.g. \r, still need to prepend the line feed to the footer
    footer = '\n' + footer;
    String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
    bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);              
  } else {
    // Prepend the CR LF to the footer
    footer = '\r\n' + footer;
    String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
    bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);  
  }

  String sUrl = 'https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content?parent_id='+folderId;
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
  req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);
  req.setMethod('POST');
  req.setEndpoint(sUrl);
  req.setBodyAsBlob(bodyBlob);
  req.setTimeout(60000);
  req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+token);
  req.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueof(req.getBodyAsBlob().size()));
  Http http = new Http();
  HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
}
```

Hopefully that helps you .

**NOTE :If size of body becomes greater than 3MB ,the HTTP callout would fail as Apex does not support body size of more than 3MB .**

Comment: sir above code is helpful for me and my file upload sucessful thanks .And i have one more issue that i want the downloadable link of uploaded file on box.com in response so what i have to do for to get link in response body just like in google drive i set   approval_prompt=force;

Comment: @sandeep Please upvote this if this helped..Also post this as other question i will respond .